# Правильная скобочная последовательность стек python

Tags: python, стек

Всем привет, кто может помочь с реализацией проверки на правильность скобочной последовательности через стек на Python.
Суть проверки я знаю, и просто через условия реализовала, но со стеком не могу понять, помогите пожалуйста.

```
def brackets_check(s):
meetings = 0
for c in s:
    if c == '(':
        meetings += 1
    elif c == ')':
        meetings -= 1
        if meetings < 0:
            return False

return meetings == 0
```

Comment: Приложите ваш код. Если вы сделали с помощью счетчика, то в некотором смысле этот счетчик и есть стек (когда вы добавляете туда 1, вы как бы туда кладёте открывающуюся скобку, а когда встречаете закрывающуюся - то достаете оттуда)

Comment: Я указала, что через условия делала. а не через счётчик

Answer (score 8, accepted):

А мне понравился этот простой и хитрый алгоритм – главное чтобы строка в нем не имела символом, кроме `()[]{}`, там даже объяснять ничего не нужно:

```
def is_correct_brackets(text):
    while '()' in text or '[]' in text or '{}' in text:
        text = text.replace('()', '')
        text = text.replace('[]', '')
        text = text.replace('{}', '')

    # Возвращаем True, если text с пустой строкой
    return not text


print(is_correct_brackets('(((())))'))  # True
print(is_correct_brackets('(((())'))  # False
print(is_correct_brackets('())))'))  # False
print(is_correct_brackets('((((){}[]{}[])))'))  # True
print(is_correct_brackets('(){}[]{}[])))'))  # False
print(is_correct_brackets('(){}[]{}[]'))  # True
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за предоставленный ответ, все понятно и просто

Comment: Красиво, хотя маленький олимпиадник внутри меня возмущается, что этот алгоритм имеет квадратичную сложность против линейной сложности алгоритма со стеком. И, кстати, в вопросе было указано, что нужен именно вариант со стеком.

Comment: @Александр, поэтому я и не стал выкладывать код с стеком :)

Answer (score 12):

На самом деле, всё очень просто.

Вы идёте от начала строки. Каждый раз, когда встречаете открывающую скобку - кладёте её в стек. Каждый раз, когда встречаете закрывающую - убираете из стека ранее положенную скобку.

Если нужно убрать скобку из стека, а их там больше не осталось - последовательность неправильная. Если после разбора строки в стеке остались лишние скобки - последовательность неправильная. Во всех остальных случаях - правильная.

Так же можно проверять последовательность, в которой есть разные скобки - круглые, квадратные, фигурные и т.п. Просто к тем проверкам, которые я описал выше, добавляется ещё проверка на то, что забираемая из стека открывающая скобка по форме должна совпадать с той закрывающей, которая у вас сейчас встретилась в строке.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, очень понятно!

Comment: Простое и легкое объяснение!